# Parsing a column into multiple columns in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, split

I'm trying to get this row to go from this:

```
Col1        Col2            Label   String                              
--------------------------------------------------------------------
6974449644  632999378491781 APDP    100.65USD/57.77USD/0167025349549
```

to this:

```
Col1        Col2            Label   old     curr   new    curr2   number               
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
6974449644  632999378491781 APDP    100.65  USD    57.77  USD     0167025349549
```

Comment: You need to reformat that as I can't make heads or tales of what you have there with everything running together like that.

Comment: Is curr always three characters?

Comment: Yes, curr is always three characters

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL Server - Splitting a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48827154/sql-server-splitting-a-string)

Comment: It is not an answer for your question but you should reed this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Answer (score 4):

One option is a little XML in concert with a CROSS APPLY

Note this assumes the Currancy is 3 characters

**Example**

```
Select A.Col1
      ,A.Col2
      ,A.Label
      ,Old   = convert(money,left(Pos1,len(Pos1)-3))
      ,Curr  = right(Pos1,3)
      ,New   = convert(money,left(Pos2,len(Pos2)-3))
      ,Curr2 = right(Pos2,3)
      ,Number= Pos3
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(A.String,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B
```

**Returns**

```
Col1        Col2            Label   Old     Curr    New    Curr2    Number
6974449644  632999378491781 APDP    100.65  USD     57.77  USD  0167025349549
```

> **Edit to See questionable data**

```
Select A.*
      ,B.*
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(A.String,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B
```

Comment: I am getting the below message when I execute this.  Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @bennett I suspect the data is not consistent.  Comment out Old,Curr,New,Curr,and Number and replace with B.*   you may see NULLs

Comment: Like this?     Select A.Col1
      ,A.Col2
      ,A.Label
      ,B.*   = convert(money,left(Pos1,len(Pos1)-3))
      ,B.* = right(Pos1,3)
      ,B.* = convert(money,left(Pos2,len(Pos2)-3))
      ,B.* = right(Pos2,3)
      ,B.* = Pos3
 From  YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(A.String,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B

Comment: Select RemarkKey
      ,PNRID
      ,Label
      ,* = convert(money,left(Pos1,len(Pos1)-3))
      ,* = right(Pos1,3)
      ,* = convert(money,left(Pos2,len(Pos2)-3))
      ,* = right(Pos2,3)
      ,* = Pos3
From  [dimRemark] dr
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(Remark,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B

Comment: Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near '='.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 15
Incorrect syntax near 'B'.

Comment: @bennett The code provided works for the sample provided.  It generated the desired results.  There are no syntax errors.  Take a peek at EDIT in the updated answer

Comment: @bennett Happy to help