# Parsing a string and comparing values to existing column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below table with the string marked "Remark" that needs to be parsed. The highlighted fares need to be compared from the columns TotalBookedFare and Remark. The only issue is that the value I need to compare under the Remark column is in the middle of a string. I've tried to parse the string but I cannot figure it out. I am using SQL Server 2008. As you can see the first row is not a match while the other three are matching.

Ideally I would like to convert the one string "Remark" to the 5 columns listed below so I can compare the TotalBookedFare to the "New" column.dionbennett

[image]

[image]

Comment: "I've tried to parse the string but I cannot figure it out."    Please post the code you tried and the error you got.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. This might be a good read for you. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: Select RemarkKey
      ,PNRID
      ,Label
      ,Old   = convert(money,left(Pos1,len(Pos1)-3))
      ,Curr  = right(Pos1,3)
      ,New   = convert(money,left(Pos2,len(Pos2)-3))
      ,Curr2 = right(Pos2,3)
      ,Number= Pos3
From  [dimRemark] dr
 Cross Apply (
                 Select Pos1 = n.value('/x[1]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos2 = n.value('/x[2]','varchar(max)')
                       ,Pos3 = n.value('/x[3]','varchar(max)')
                  From  (Select cast('<x>' + replace(Remark,'/','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml) as n) X
             ) B

Comment: Msg 537, Level 16, State 3, Line 1
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @TabAlleman If truly interested, OP it referring to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48832591/parsing-a-column-into-multiple-columns-in-sql-server-2008/48832764#48832764

Comment: Code does not format nicely in comments at all. You would be better to edit your question (https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48834256/edit) and put the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work

```
select substring(
remark, --string base
charindex ('/', 'xyz/57.77usd/zyx') + 1, 
--starting position is location one to the right of first instance of / character (5)
charindex ('u', 'xyz/57.77usd/zyx', charindex ('/', 'xyz/57.77usd/zyx')) - charindex ('/', 'xyz/57.77usd/zyx') - 1
--length is the location of the first instance of the u character
--starting from the location of first instance of the / character (10)
--then subtracted by the location of the first instance of the / character (4) 
--and then an additional 1 resulting in the length of the string to be extracted (5)
)
```

The string I put in there is just a more concrete example, if you replace it with **Remark**, it should extract the substring for each row. You could even modify it with some copy/pasting to get each of those columns you were looking for.